# Mysql How to multiplication two colums each row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables named test1, test2. I have inserted values into two tables. The problem is, I want to multiply value of two together. Can anyone help me?

```
table test1
id | cola | colb
1  | 0,5  | 5
2  | 0,6  | 6

table test1
id | colc | cold
1  | 0,7  | 7
2  | 0,8  | 8

SELECT cola,colb,colc,cold,(cola*t2.colc)AS er FROM test1 t1, test2 t2
```

Comment: which columns do you want to participate in the multiplication? Please share your expected output. And what does it mean `0,5` under `cola`?

Comment: I want to participate  cola and colc . Under these cola, colb, colc,cold are value

Comment: Add your expected output. It's unclear

Comment: I mean. why result is only 0 for each row .  I want return result of cola and colc

Comment: Add your expected output. It's unclear

Comment: why there are comma separated values in `cola` and `colc`?

Comment: i want result is return 0,5 * 0,7 and 0,6*0,8.

Comment: @Louis it is 0,5 or 0.5?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use query like below:

```
SELECT t1.cola,t1.colb,t2.colc,t2.cold,(t1.colb*t2.cold)AS er FROM test1 t1, test2 t2
```

Comment: thank Milan Gupta. but i want to participate cola and col c in the multiplication. If i change 0.5 ,it is ok. but if it is 0,5 do not

Comment: May be you can try something like this int colaValue = '0,5', colbValue = '0.6'
int finalValueA = colaValue.replace(/\,/g,''), finalValueB = colbValue.replace(/\,/g,''); And then multiply finalValueA and finalValueB to get desired result.

Comment: where try something?